# C++ coding obstacle

Tags: visual-c++

}

```
int North, north;
cout << "You enter the forest, where would you like to go.\n" << endl;
cin >> North;

int Yes;
cout << "You appear in front of a cave, you see a sign saying. Canifis Cave BEWARE!\n" << endl;
cout << "Are you going to enter. (1.Yes/2.No?)\n" << endl;
cin >> Yes;


cout << "You enter the cave.. It is lit by torches only going westward. Are you going to follow the lit path? (Yes/No)\n" << endl;
cin >> Yes;


cout << "You see the the goblins.\n" << endl;
cout << "They are asleep and you see the Sword Of A Thousand Truths against the wall on a makeshift stand.\n" << endl;

int pickOption;
cout << "You can either kill the goblins by throwing a torch off the wall on them and retrieve the sword.\n";
    cout << "Or you can just quietly take it and leave\n" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Kill goblins with torch then take The Sword Of A Thousand Truths.\n" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Take The Sword Of A Thousand Truths quietly and leave.\n" << endl;
    cin >> pickOption;

    switch (pickOption)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "The Goblins burned to death, congratulations!. you retrieve The Sword Of A Thousand Truths.\n" << endl;
        cout << "You make your way back to Doric and give him the family heirloom he thanks you.\n";
        cout << "You then leave and continue on your journey after finishing Doric's Quest.\n";
            cout << "CONGRATULATIONS ON COMPLETEING DORIC'S QUEST!!\n" << endl;
            break;

    case 2:
        cout << "You sneak by the goblins, retrieve the family heirloom and make your way out the cave unnoticed.\n" << endl;
        cout << "You make your way back to Doric and give him the family heirloom he thanks you.\n";
        cout << "You then leave and continue on your journey after finishing Doric's Quest.\n";
        cout << "CONGRATULATIONS ON COMPLETEING DORIC'S QUEST!!\n" << endl;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
```

}

After the go North part it does not allow you to type in the cin for the rest of the questions it just skips and posts all of the cout information ,can anyone help? I dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Since you used `<<endl;` A new line character is been left in the buffer.This character is read by the cin that follows.So remove those `<<endl;` and the code should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your arrangement is very bad. Second, you need to provide more information about what you are trying to achieve? What do you input in the first 'cin' that makes it continue straight without stopping? Please note that you have used int for the variable North and north therefore anything other than numbers will make the program display the rest of the 'couts' and terminate if there is no error handling implemented.

I think the problem you are facing is because you are entering alphabets instead of number for the int inputs.

> I can run this codes without any problem. Screenshot for proof.

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, the values entered are  not checked at all. I can enter 3 for the question of 1 for yes and 2 for no and it still continues. Include your if statements or whichever way you use to do the checking and then proceed to the next step. Make sure you clearly state the input that should be entered by the users. Have proper variable classes for different criterias.

If you don't know how to achieve or complete this or need further help do comment. I will edit this post with the codes.